# Fluttter Scaffold ' invalid credentials' message is not showing on login

Tags: flutter

I have an app with a login page that requires and email and a password. It should bring a scaffold message at the bottom of the screen in the event that the login is not successful that is, when the code is not 200. Currently, when the login button is pressed with wrong credentials, the loading circle persists and nothing changes. This is what the error page looks like:
[image: loading circle persists on login page]

This is the code with the scaffold function:

```
  void _showScaffold(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          label: 'Try Again',
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('login');
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
  }
```

This is the login function where it is implemented:

```
_login() async {
    var data = {
      'email': emailController.text,
      'password': passwordController.text,
    };

    var res = await Network().authData(data, 'auth/login');

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = json.decode(res.body);
      var tdata = body['data'];
      var access = tdata['accessToken'];
      var user = tdata['user'];
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(access));
      localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(user));
      return Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('dashboard');
    } else {
      return setState(() {
        _showScaffold('Invalid Credentials');
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is the code for the on pressed section of the login button:

```
 if (_isLoading)
                  SizedBox(
                      width: 250,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                          const Color.fromRGBO(46, 88, 0, 1),
                        )),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            _isLoading = false;
                          });
                          await _login();
                          if (!mounted) return;
                          setState(() {
                            _isLoading = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                else
                  const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(46, 88, 0, 1))),
```

This is the code for the whole login_widget.dart file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mne/Network/api.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginWidgetState createState() => _LoginWidgetState();
}

class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _showScaffold(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          label: 'Try Again',
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('login');
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
  }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   _showScaffold('Invalid Credentials');
  // }

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  _login() async {
    var data = {
      'email': emailController.text,
      'password': passwordController.text,
    };

    var res = await Network().authData(data, 'auth/login');

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = json.decode(res.body);
      var tdata = body['data'];
      var access = tdata['accessToken'];
      var user = tdata['user'];
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(access));
      localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(user));
      return Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('dashboard');
    } else {
      return setState(() {
        _showScaffold('Invalid Credentials');
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _isObscure = true;
  bool _validate = false;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: const Text('Email',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 60.0,
                        width: 375,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Field cannot be empty';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorText:
                                _validate ? 'Field cannot be empty' : null,
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Email Address',
                          ),
                        ))),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: const Text('Password',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 60.0,
                        width: 375,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: _isObscure,
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Field cannot be empty';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(_isObscure
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                                  });
                                }),
                            errorText:
                                _validate ? 'Field cannot be empty' : null,
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Password',
                          ),
                        ))),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text(
                        'Forgot password?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 116, 9, 1),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('reset');
                      },
                    )),
                if (_isLoading)
                  SizedBox(
                      width: 250,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                          const Color.fromRGBO(46, 88, 0, 1),
                        )),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            _isLoading = false;
                          });
                          await _login();
                          if (!mounted) return;
                          setState(() {
                            _isLoading = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                else
                  const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(46, 88, 0, 1))),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to make the scaffold message show up and redirect the user back to the login page. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have a problem here calling .of(context) after an async call. You might want to look into FutureBuilder. It allows you to wait for an async method (such as login) and execute some UI change afterwards. Also, it seems weird to call return setState(...). Return shouldn't be needed

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner so I don't fully understand but i will look into future builder, thank you